# QuantLib: How to check or access the QuantLib version in conda prompt or spyder?

Tags: programming, quantlib

I didnt find the answer in QuantLib library. This will surely help to get the track of quantlib version and installed package versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import QuantLib as ql
print(ql.__version__)
```

should work.  There's also a `ql.__hexversion__` attribute.